# Edit arrays using angular-xeditable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-xeditable

I pull some objects from my api using ngResource an then I show them in a table. Thats ok.. the problem become when I try to make 'tags' attribute editable using angular-xeditable but are treated as string and there isn't something like "ngList" on angular-xeditable.
The only solution I can think of is serialize that "tags" attribute to "tagsString" on my service and unserialize it once $save() was called.. there is a more elegant solution?

Object:

```
{
    "id": "yP8",
    "uploadDate": "2012-10-03T12:52:59-0300",
    "statusChangeDate": "2012-10-03T12:52:59-0300",
    "status": 0,
    "type": 1,
    "mimeType": "JPEG",
    "title": "title-36868",
    "tags": [
        'some-tag',
        'fancy-tag'
    ],
    "language": "en",
    "interactions": {
        "likes": 12371,
        "dislikes": 15,
        "comments": 81
    },
    "published": true
}
```

Controller:

```
app.controller( 'ContentsCtrl', function CommentsCtrl( $scope, Contents ) {
    $scope.contents = Contents.query();
});
```

Template:

```
<tr ng:repeat="content in contents.content">
    <td>{{content.id}}</td>
    <td ng:click="content.images.showFull=!content.images.showFull">
        <img src="{{content.images.thumbnail.url}}" ng:show="!content.images.showFull">
        <img src="{{content.images.medium.url}}" ng:show="content.images.showFull">
    </td>
    <td>{{content.status}}</td>
    <td>
        <span editable-text="content.title" e-required>{{content.title}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span editable-text="content.tags">{{content.tags}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>{{content.language}}</td>
</tr>
```

EDIT:

Demo (by Sebastian Gärtner):
http://plnkr.co/edit/ttPNgHXUZKmaJZ9IuB2N?p=preview

Comment: Can you wire up an example using jsfiddle?

Comment: Contents.query() looks like a promise. If it is, this will break in newer versions of Angular as it does not unwrap promises automatically anymore FYI.

Comment: You can submit an enhancement to angular-xeditable or even better a pull request ;)

Answer (score 2):

What about solving it with another directive. Not with xeditable.

Like: http://decipherinc.github.io/angular-tags/

You do want to have the tags editable?
What input mechanism do you want to have?

What about another ng-repeat for the tags to make them each an single input field and maybe an mechanism for add and delete tags.

Comment: In order to solve it and reach the deadline I'm now using ng-tags-input combined with ng:show.... but im looking for a better solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="tag in content.tags track by $index">
    <span editable-text="content.tags[$index]">{{tag}}</span> 
</div>
```

The trick is to wire up the correct model-value with the *editable-text* directive (using the *$index* iterator in this case).

Comment: That don't cover add/delete actions

Answer (score 0):

The [Editable Table example](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#editable-table) on the angular x-editable page has something that *almost* accomplishes this. By wrapping each string in you list in an object, you can apply arbitrary properties to it - in this case, temporary values which you can key save/delete functionality off of in onCancel and onBeforeSave handlers.

Object:

```
{
    tags: [
        {name: 'some-tag'},
        {name: 'fancy-tag'}
    ]
};
```

HTML:

```
<form editable-form name="tagForm" onBeforeSave="cleanBeforeSave()" onCancel="cleanOnCancel()">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="tag in contents.tags | filter:filterDeleted">
            <span editable-text="tag.name" e-name="name"> {{tag.name}} </span> 
            <button ng-click="deleteTag($index)" ng-show="tagForm.$visible">x</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <span ng-show="tagForm.$visible">
        <button type="button" ng-click="addTag()">New</button>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
        <button type="button" ng-click="tagForm.$cancel()">Cancel</button>

    </span>
    <span ng-hide="tagForm.$visible">
        <button type="button" ng-click="tagForm.$show()">Edit</button>    
    </span>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller( 'TagCtrl', function TagCtrl( $scope, Contents ) {
    $scope.contents = Contents.query();

    $scope.filterDeleted = function(obj) {
        return obj.isDeleted !== true;
    };

    $scope.addTag = function() {
        $scope.contents.tags.push({name:"", isNew:true});
    };

    $scope.removeTag = function(index) {
        $scope.contents.tags[index].isDeleted = true;
    };

    $scope.cleanBeforeSave = function() {
        // go backwards, so deleting doesn't mess up i's count
        for (var i = $scope.contents.tags.length; i--;) {
            var tag = $scope.contents.tags[i];
            if (tag.isDeleted) {
                $scope.contents.tags.splice(i, 1);
            }
            if (tag.isNew) {
                delete tag.isNew;
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.cleanOnCancel = function() {
        // go backwards, so deleting doesn't mess up i's count
        for (var i = $scope.contents.tags.length; i--;) {
            var tag = $scope.contents.tags[i];
            if (tag.isDeleted) {
                delete tag.isDeleted;
            }
            if (tag.isNew) {
                $scope.contents.tags.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
    };
});
```